# Scala Seq.grouped eating my iterator

Tags: java, scala, iterator

As a C# programmer I have a sketchy understanding of Java / Scala iterator design.

I am trying to (lazily - for the source may be big) read records from a `RecordReader` (in some third party library). I need to do some additional work every 100 records.

```
for (group <- reader.iterator.zipWithIndex.grouped(100)) {
  for ((record, i) <- group) {
    println(i + "|" + record.key)
  }
  // ...
}
```

This gives me the very last record, repeatedly, each time.

If I don't use `grouped`, it works fine and I get each record. Am I missing something about lazy streaming or Java iterators?

Comment: The problem is either in the code you're not showing or in the third party library's implementation of `Iterator`, since I can't reproduce your problem with classes from the standard library.

Comment: Thanks. My feeling is that the third party iterator is behaving badly - but the question is whether this is really the case, or whether it is something I have misunderstood.

Comment: Astonishing that my reasonably carefully written, polite question has been negatively voted. Way to go for the Scala community.

Comment: Maybe the vote is negative because from the information you've given there is no way to answer your question. To find out whether the 3rd party library is behaving badly, switch out its iterator with one from the standard library and see whether your problem disappears.

Comment: Indeed it does - but that couldn't possibly tell me whether I have understood enough about Java iterators and Scala sequence streaming to say that it is the `RecordReader` that is doing something *wrong*. For that I was hoping for some advice from people who know Scala better than me.

Comment: and who can read minds apparently

Comment: If the answer is "That should not happen if the iterator is implemented according to the Java contract for iterators, so the third party library must have a bug" that would great! But what more relevant information can I give? :-(

Comment: For one thing, nobody knows what makes you think that you get the same record each time. Do you just print them? If so, that should not happen. Also, do you have the source of the 3rd party library? If yes, post the implementation of the `.iterator` method.

Comment: I've edited the question to show a println. I don't have the source to hand unfort. Thanks for helping, Kim!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To troubleshoot, try to decorate your iterator in an another iterator that prints what is going on:

```
def wrap[T](i: Iterator[T]) = new Iterator[T] {
  def hasNext = { val b = i.hasNext; println("hasNext => " + b); b }
  def next() = { val n = i.next(); println("next() => " + n); n }
}

val reader = Iterator.from(20).take(10).toList
for (group <- wrap(reader.iterator).zipWithIndex.grouped(5)) {
  for ((v, i) <- group) println("[" + i + "] = " + v)
}
```

Call wrap on the iterator, the very first time you instantiate the iterator. This will print something like:

```
hasNext => true
hasNext => true
next() => 20
hasNext => true
next() => 21
hasNext => true
```

This should help you determine if the iterator is ill behaved... It could be for instance that the library does not deal correctly with calling `hasNext` multiple times without calling `next`. In that case you can modify `wrap` so that you make the iterator behave correctly. One more thing, from the symptoms, it feels like you've already consume the iterator before the grouped is called. So be extra careful and check if you've used the same iterator reference before.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem might be that `Record.key` just returns the current value of some variable that is mutated as the iterator is consumed 
(as opposed to having the record to actually capture the key value at construction time).
An example will prbably make it clearer. 
First, let's use the scala REPL to cook up some test code that **not** exhibit the problem:

```
case class Record( key: Int )
def getRecordIterator: Iterator[Record] = {
  var currentKey: Int = 0
  (1 to 10).iterator.map{ i => 
    currentKey += 1
    new Record( currentKey )
  }
}
```

Then we can try to iterate without using `grouped`:

```
for ((record, i) <- getRecordIterator.zipWithIndex) {
  println(i + "|" + record)
}
```

This gives us (as expected)

```
0|Record(1)
1|Record(2)
2|Record(3)
3|Record(4)
4|Record(5)
5|Record(6)
6|Record(7)
7|Record(8)
8|Record(9)
9|Record(10)
```

And then using `grouped`:

```
for (group <- getRecordIterator.zipWithIndex.grouped(3)) {
  for ((record, i) <- group) {
    println(i + "|" + record)
  }
  println("---")
}
```

Which gives:

```
0|Record(1)
1|Record(2)
2|Record(3)
---
3|Record(4)
4|Record(5)
5|Record(6)
---
6|Record(7)
7|Record(8)
8|Record(9)
---
9|Record(10)
---
```

Until now, all is well.

Now let's change the definition of `Record` slightly:

```
trait Record {
  def key: Int
  override def toString = "Record(" + key + ")"
}
def getRecordIterator: Iterator[Record] = {
  var currentKey: Int = 0
  (1 to 10).iterator.map{ i => 
    currentKey += 1
    new Record{ def key = currentKey }
  }    
}
```

With this change, we still have the same result when not using `grouped`, but here is what we get when we do use `group`:

```
0|Record(3)
1|Record(3)
2|Record(3)
---
3|Record(6)
4|Record(6)
5|Record(6)
---
6|Record(9)
7|Record(9)
8|Record(9)
---
9|Record(10)
---
```

The source of the problem is that the mere fact of calling `next` on our iterator mutates the value that is returned by `Record.get`.
The problem can be illustrated even more trivially:

```
val it = getRecordIterator
val r1 = it.next
println(r1) // prints "Record(1)" as expected
val r2 = it.next
println(r2) // prints "Record(2)" as expected
println(r1) // this now prints "Record(2)", not "Record(1)" anymore!
```